# How to iterate through a hashmap to get every fourth key, value pair?

Tags: java, android, loops, listview, hashmap

I have a hashmap like this;

```
key value1
key value2
key value3
key value4
key1 value5
key1 value6
key1 value7
key1 value8
key2 value9
... and so on
```

Now I want to put this in a ListView which contains **four rows**, and in row1, I want:

```
key value1
key1 value5
key2 value9
key3 value13 and so on till end
```

And in row2, I want:

```
key value2
key1 value6
key2 value10
key3 value14 and so on till end
```

And then the same in rows 3 and 4. There are always only 4 rows.

I am having trouble iterating through this. Here is the code I wrote, but it doesn't work.

```
String[] fourrows = hashMap.get("KEY");
for (int i=0;i<fourrows.length;i++) {
HashMap<String, String> listHashMap = new HashMap<>();
listHashMap.put("TA",  "ROW VALUE "+fourrows[i]);

for (int j=1;j<hashMap.entrySet().size();j+=4) {
String val = hashMap.values().toArray()[j].toString();
String key = hashMap.get(hashMap.keySet().toArray()[0]).toString();

listHashMap.put("IA", key);
listHashMap.put("XA", val);
incmStmtList.add(listHashMap);
}
}

//Then I pass TA, IA and XA to a simple list adapter and add it to a listView.
incmAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), incmStmtList,R.layout.content_results, new String[]{"TA", "IA", "XA"},new int[]{R.id.ta, R.id.ia, R.id.tota});
listView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
listView.setAdapter(incmAdapter);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't look at your code, but just to note, HashMaps do not keep their insertion order. You may want to use a LinkedHashMap.

Comment: *Map* itself is not designed to have *index*. You should not expect a map to keep the items in some order.

Comment: How is ListView relevant?

Comment: @BorisvanKatwijk ListView contains four rows - each having one particular value of a particular key in the map... inside each row is a couple of textviews, and multiple IA and XA values should be added to each. Hope that clarifies. The question really is how to do that.

Comment: @BorisvanKatwijk I have edited the question with how I pass the values to my listView. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using HashMap use Multimap. And based on key get the value in Collection object. then from each Collection add one one value on all the list.

Multimap myList = ArrayListMultimap.create();

```
            myList.put("key","value1");
            myList.put("key","value2");
            myList.put("key","value3");
            myList.put("key","value4");
            myList.put("key1","value5");
            myList.put("key1","value6");
            myList.put("key1","value7");
            myList.put("key1","value8");
            myList.put("key2","value9");
            myList.put("key2","value10");
            myList.put("key2","value11");
            myList.put("key2","value12");
            myList.put("key3","value13");
            myList.put("key3","value14");
            myList.put("key3","value15");
            myList.put("key3","value16");
```

Then get all keys from list

```
  Set myKeySet = myList.keySet();
  Object[] keys = myKeySet.toArray();
```

Now you have set of all key. then

```
    HashMap<String, String> listHashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, String> listHashMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, String> listHashMap3 = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, String> listHashMap4 = new HashMap<>();
```

Now add the value to every list

```
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        List<String> keyval = (List)myList.get((String)keys[i]);
        listHashMap1.put((String)keys[i],keyval.get(0));
        listHashMap2.put((String)keys[i],keyval.get(1));
        listHashMap3.put((String)keys[i],keyval.get(2));
        listHashMap4.put((String)keys[i],keyval.get(3));
     }
```

Now you have set of four row list. This Multimap is using google guava.
 So you need to implement guava in your gradle as below:
 implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:26.0-jre'

Answer (score 0):

From the code you supplied it seems that the source `hashMap` is of type `Map<String, String[]>`.

You could iterate over the entries of the map, and for each entry store the four values in different result containers. Since you indicated the result containers should be maps as well:

```
    Map<String, String> one = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> two = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> three = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> four = new HashMap<>();

    hashMap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
        String[] values = entry.getValue();
        one.put(entry.getKey(), values[0]);
        two.put(entry.getKey(), values[1]);
        three.put(entry.getKey(), values[2]);
        four.put(entry.getKey(), values[3]);
    });
```

Note: assuming every key always has exactly four values.

Comment: But how do I pass only four values to the TA link on the Simple list adapter, and multiple IA and XA values under each TA?

Comment: I have edited the question with how I pass the values to my listView. Please check and let me know.